Fractional scaling problem on Ubuntu
I have recently switched to Linux and I am running it at 125% scaling. Most of the apps I am installing looks blurry and the problem is solved once I switch to 100% scaling, but every thing looks small and unusable.(I was able to fix Vs Code, but PyCharm is still blurry) Please help.

Please add more details about your hardware. Is it very new?

Please post it as an answer. Also, give 24.10 a try (you can try from live USB it before you decide to install). Usually, newer versions of Ubuntu have better support for recent hardware

It is 2024 Acer SwiftGo14 16 GB ryzen 7 7730u . Also my fingerprint scanner does not work which i came to that drivers for it are not available yet. I have fixed the blur screen issue yesterday by switching scaling to 100 % and turning on large text in accessibility settings. (without large text the UI is basically unusable)
